# How to quickly answer email with an audio note

Tags: audio, email, thunderbird

Sometimes I need to give very long answers to some emails and I am very bad at typing, so if I know that person and I have her/his phone number, I send her an audio note via Whatsapp. But there are many others for which I do not have their phone numbers. So I would like to send them, via email and using Thunderbird, in the easiest and quickest possible way, an audio note. I found that in Mac, I can record an audio note, then put in on my dropbox public folder, then copy the shared URL, and then past it into the email, but this is a bit long. Can you suggest a more practical way?

Comment: I have a feeling you usually respond with the same kind of message. Couldn't you compose one single email response and save it somewhere so you can just copy/paste that message? Maybe ask help to compose that response once? Most people won't like to get an audio response anyway.

Comment: Audio recordings are not that large, so you could just attach the file to the email.

Comment: Which Operating System do you use, is it OS X (Mac)? The best quickest steps will be tailored to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

1. [Use the dictation (voice to text) within Mac OS X](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-dictation-mh40584/mac)
2. Use the [voice memos app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206775) to record in Mac OS X, then hit share or drag & drop recording to Thunderbird
3. [If your Max OS X has Siri](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204389#mac) (voice assistant) I guess you can ask her `Hey Siri record a voice memo` or `Hey Siri Open Voice Memos`. Or if you default email app IS thunderbird maybe she can dictate (voice to text) to your email:
   `Hey Siri send email to [name] about [subject] and say [message]`

Might get better answers on the [Apple Stack Exchange site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) if that is the OS you want assistance on. [OS X has an Automator app](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/welcome/mac) that is supposed to help with things like this.